# $\langle a, b\rangle = d\mathbb{Z}$, relation of $d$ to $a, b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b$ be positive integers, and consider the subgroup $\langle a, b\rangle$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ they generate. I know that $$\langle a, b\rangle = d\mathbb{Z}$$for some positive integer $d$. My question is, what is $d$ in relation to $a, b$?

Answer (score 1):

We will show that $d = \text{gcd}(a,b)$

Firstly, note that we must have $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b$, because we have, by assumption, $a,b \in d\mathbb{Z}$.

It follows that $\text{gcd}(a,b) \mid d$.

On the other hand, we can write (using [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)):

$$
\text{gcd}(a,b) = ra+sb
$$

for some integers $r,s$.

Thus $\text{gcd}(a,b) = ra+sb \in \langle a,b \rangle = d\mathbb{Z}$, and so it follows that $d \mid \text{gcd}(a,b)$

Hence $d = \text{gcd}(a,b)$

Answer (score 0):

$d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. This is easy to see via Bezout's lemma. Note that $\langle a, b\rangle$ is actually even an ideal in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

$d=\gcd(a,b)$. This is because every $x\in\langle a,b\rangle$ can be written in the form $x=sa+tb$ for some $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$. Recall that $d$ being the greatest common divisor (or any divisor) of $a$ and $b$ means that $d|(sa+tb)$. So, $\langle a,b\rangle\subseteq d\mathbb{Z}$. Conversely, since there is a choice of $s$ and $t$ for which $as+tb=d$ (this is a basic fact about the $\gcd$ of two numbers), we also have that $d\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\langle a,b\rangle$.